# Dynamically change custom host URL of osm Plugin in a QML Map

Tags: qt, dictionary, plugins, qml, host

I have a custom chart host with several tiled maps in a directory structure:

```
http://host/New_York/
http://host/Washington/
http://host/Montreal/
```

The QML application has a ComboBox component that allows the user to select which chart he wants to display.

The Map component uses the `osm` Plugin with a  PluginParameter pointing to the URL to use for the chart. I thought I could simply dynamically assign a value to this PluginParameter, but it does not work, the value remains unchanged even after assigning it. I also tried destroying the Plugin object, recreating it  and assigning it to the Map object, but I get an error saying that the `plugin` property is `ReadOnly`.

What is the proper way to dynamically change the custom host URL of a Plugin object used by a Map component?

```
    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"

        PluginParameter { id: charturl; name: "osm.mapping.custom.host"; }
    }

    Map {
        id: mapview
        plugin: mapPlugin
        activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[supportedMapTypes.length - 1]
...

    ComboBox {
...
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            charturl.value = cbItems.get(currentIndex).url
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Plugin can only be written once, so you cannot change it later, so in this you will have to create a new map using Loader:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

import QtLocation 5.14
import QtPositioning 5.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ComboBox {
            id: combobox
            model: [
                "http://host/New_York/",
                "http://host/Washington/",
                "http://host/Montreal/"
            ]
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            onActivated: changeHost()
        }
        Loader{
            id: loader
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            onStatusChanged: if (loader.status === Loader.Ready) console.log('Loaded')
        }
        Component.onCompleted: changeHost()
    }
    function changeHost(){
        var item = loader.item
        var zoomLevel = item ? item.zoomLevel: 14
        var center = item ? item.center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)

        loader.setSource("MapComponent.qml", {
                             "host": combobox.currentValue,
                             "center": center,
                             "zoomLevel": zoomLevel}
                         )
    }
}
```

**MapComponent.qml**

```
import QtLocation 5.14

Map {
    id: map
    property string host: ""
    plugin: Plugin {
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.custom.host"
            value: map.host
        }
    }
    activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[supportedMapTypes.length - 1]
}
```